# ajax_comments prevent plupload

Tags: 7, comments

I'll start things first

When ajax_comments is off all fine. Images loading successfully
http://imageshack.us/a/img14/4577/p0ug.png

But when ajax_comments is on, Plupload not loading images. Plupaload form duplicate itself, and no uploading images
http://imageshack.us/a/img534/2013/57lz.png

I have no errors, JS console no errors too. I can't understand how to fix...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like plupload needs to use Drupal's `jQuery.once ` to prevent duplication. You should raise the issue on the plupload module issue queue.

Comment: @DavidThomas I looked in plupload JS-file, there everywhere using jquery.once

Comment: OK, probably a different issue then. Somehow attaching itself incorrectly to the ajax response, not sure from here.